# How do I revoke access to java applet on OSX when there's an error in the control panel

Tags: macos, java

I can't access the screenr.com java applet on my mac.

Poking around the java preferences, I saw an odd entry with a red circle (I assume that means to deny access?) for it in the security section.  When I highlight that entry and hit the remove button, I get an error, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Is there somewhere I can go on the filesystem to clear out all of these?  Other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out.

Delete a file called com.apple.java.security.plist in your ~/Library/Preferences/... and everything works out.